# Error django " MultiValueDictKeyError at /employeeUpdate/ 'id' " affter I edit data

Tags: python, html, css, django, web-applications

Error django " MultiValueDictKeyError at /employeeUpdate/ 'id' " affter I edit data.
Here my code in views.py

```
def employeeUpdate(request):
    id = request.POST['id']
    emp_username = request.POST['emp_username']
    emp_password = request.POST['emp_password']
    emp_identification_code = request.POST['emp_identification_code']
    content = employee.objects.get(pk = id)
    content.emp_username = emp_username
    content.emp_password = emp_password
    content.emp_identification_code = emp_identification_code

    if(employee.objects.filter(emp_username=emp_username)):
        messages.success(request, 'Username already exists')
        return redirect("/employeeUpdate")
    elif(employee.objects.filter(emp_identification_code=emp_identification_code)):
        messages.success(request, 'Identification already exists')
        return redirect("/employeeUpdate")
    else:
        content.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Update already !!!')
        return redirect("/employeeBoard")
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access `request.POST['id']`which is not does not exist. You can try to access default value from dictionary if it does not exist by using

```
id =request.POST.get('id', default_value)
```

if you want to access the `id` of current user then you can try

```
id = request.user.id
```